# Update and append new rows based on index value python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two dataframes `DF1`, `DF2` which have the same type of data and share some index values but not all

```
        DF1    
 index, a, b, c
[ abc   1, 3, 6 ]
[ acb   2, 4, 5 ]
[ cab   6, 5, 2 ]
[ bac   3, 6, 2 ]
[ bca   6, 8, 3 ]

        DF2
 index, a, b, d
[ abc   4, 7, 3 ]
[ kde   2, 5, 8 ]
[ lat   7, 2, 6 ]
[ bac   0, 4, 4 ]
[ bca   3, 6, 8 ]
```

as a result I want to achieve the following

1.) Add column D to `DF1` based on the index match

2.) Add index and rows from `DF2`which are not present in `DF1`

```
        RESULT   
 index, a, b, c, d
[ abc   1, 3, 6, 3 ]
[ acb   2, 4, 5, - ]
[ cab   6, 5, 2, - ]
[ bac   3, 6, 2, 4 ]
[ bca   6, 8, 3, 8 ]
[ kde   2, 5, -, 8 ]
[ lat   7, 2, -, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

Create data:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,6,3,6],'b':[3,4,5,6,8],'c':[6,5,2,2,3]},index=['abc','acb','cab','bac','bca'])
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,2,7,0,3],'b':[7,5,2,4,6],'d':[3,8,6,4,8]},index=['abc','kde','lat','bac','bca'])

df_combo = DF1.combine_first(DF2)
print(df_combo)

       a    b    c    d
abc  1.0  3.0  6.0  3.0
acb  2.0  4.0  5.0  NaN
bac  3.0  6.0  2.0  4.0
bca  6.0  8.0  3.0  8.0
cab  6.0  5.0  2.0  NaN
kde  2.0  5.0  NaN  8.0
lat  7.0  2.0  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: I am getting the AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' when combing df's

Comment: Be sure to set your index using df.set_index('index') in both datafames

Comment: I believe there is a bug here - I set the indexes and I am still getting "DataFrame object has no attribute 'dtype'".  In the error message it also looks like combine_first is expecting a series

Comment: @AranFreel are you still having a problem?

Comment: I am still having problems, unfortunately

Comment: what if I wanted to also update DF1 with the values of DF2? `df.update` does not add indexes

Comment: @MartimPassos try `DF2.combine_first(DF1)` reverse it.  Does that work?